# MySQL: Can a join do the trick?

Tags: php, mysql

I have those tables:

```
------------------------
- user:
----- id    
----- name     
------------------------
- user_has_element:
----- user_id     
----- element_id     
------------------------
- element:
----- id
----- name
----- price
------------------------
```

My goal is to create a function that takes a user name and some element names,
and returns the following info about every element passed to it:

- name: the element name
- price: the element price
- isOwned: whether or not the element is owned by the given user

So for instance, let's say user John has 3 elements E.A, E.B and E.C.

If I call my function with the following arguments:

```
    name: John
    elements: E.A, E.B, E.C, E.D
```

It should return an array like this:

```
        0:
            - name: E.A                            
            - isOwned: 1
        1:
            - name: E.B                            
            - isOwned: 1
        2:
            - name: E.C                            
            - isOwned: 1
        3:
            - name: E.D                            
            - isOwned: 0
```

For now, all I've got is a query that returns the elements owned by an user:

```
select e.name as elementName
from user u
inner join user_has_element h on h.user_id=u.id
inner join element e on e.id=h.element_id
where
    u.name='AAA'
    and
    (
        e.name='E.A'
        or
        e.name='E.B'
        or
        e.name='E.C'
    )
```

From there, I know how to work my way to the goal with the help of some php code,
but I wondered if this was possible with mysql only?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can select from the element table first and use `LEFT JOIN` from there with subquery to check for user_id of name passed. Assuming you function is getting php variables like:

```
$user = 'John';
$elements = array('E.A', 'E.B', 'E.C', 'E.D');
$elements = implode("','",$elements);
```

Your SQL could look something like this:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        e.name as elementName,
        e.price as elementPrice,
        (h.element_id IS NOT NULL) as isOwned
    FROM element e
    LEFT JOIN user_has_element h ON
    (
        h.element_id = e.id 
        AND h.user_id =
        (
            SELECT id 
            FROM user u
            WHERE u.name '" . $user . "'
        )
    )
    WHERE e.name IN ('" . $elements . "')
    ";
```

And of course, don't forget to escape your variables to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, you found it !! $sql = "
    SELECT 
        e.name as elementName,
        e.price as elementPrice,
        (h.element_id IS NOT NULL) as isOwned
    FROM element e
    LEFT JOIN user_has_element h ON
    (
        h.element_id = e.id 
        AND h.user_id =
        (
            SELECT id 
            FROM user u
            WHERE u.name = '" . $user . "'
        )
    )
    LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id=b.user_id
    WHERE e.name IN ('" . $elements . "')
    ";